# Correct way to calculate the size for malloc() and realloc()?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I've seen `malloc()` and `realloc()` used a bunch of different ways. After testing the various ways out, I was curious to know if I was using them correctly ?

First I tried

```
int size = rowSize * colSize;
int newSize = size + rowSize;

int *randomNum;

randomNum = malloc(size * sizeof *randomNum);

randomNum = realloc(randomNum, newSize * sizeof *randomNum);
```

and that works!!

Then I tried,

```
int size = rowSize * colSize;
int newSize = size + rowSize;

int *randomNum;

randomNum = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

randomNum = realloc(randomNum, newSize * sizeof(int));
```

and that works also. So I guess I don't know why I'd use `sizeof *some_name` versus `sizeof(int)` ?
Is there a reason to use one over the other?

Comment: To be correct, you should check `realloc()`'s return value prior to overwriting the old one.

Comment: Thanks glglgl, could you give me an example?

Comment: @glglgl, ok think I found an example, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're the same.  The reason to use your former example is to ease maintenance later if you decide to change types.

That said, don't use `realloc` like that - if it fails, you'll leak the original `randomNum` allocation.

Comment: So then the second one is better, although it's more maintenance?

Comment: What? No, the first one is better, IMHO.  Others may think differently; they're same, so it hardly matters.

Answer (score 1):

After accept answer

@Carl Norum answer is good, but was mostly done with this and it adds a few points.

Use of `sizeof(*pointer)` or `sizeof(type)` is a style issue.
I find the 1st easier to maintain and less error prone.  Applies for both `malloc()`, `realloc()`.

```
size_t count = rowSize * colSize;
int *randomNum = malloc(count * sizeof *randomNum);
int *randomNum = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
```

Example `realloc()`

```
int *randomNum = NULL;
...
size_t N = foo();

// If N is zero, (a strange case) one might want to increase it.
// Successfully allocating 0 bytes may return NULL or a non-NULL pointer.

int *randomNum2 = realloc(randomNum, N * sizeof(*randomNum));
if (randomNum2 == NULL && N > 0) {
  // randomNum still contains what it use to.
  Handle_allocation_failure();
  ...
  free(randomNum);
}
else {
  // The happy path
  randomNum = randomNum2;
  ...
  free(randomNum);
}
```

Comment: @jc72  For more `realloc()` details, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36662/critique-of-realloc-wrapper